# Questions about Raft consensus configuration

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, ibm-blockchain

I have a question about raft configuration on Hyperledger Fabric 1.41, why on configtx.yaml file you configure all your raft orderers to listen on 7050 port, however on the docker-compose file all the orderers are listening to 7050,8050,9050, etc ? How does this works?

Configtx.yaml

```
 Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            OrdererType: etcdraft
            EtcdRaft:
                Consenters:
                - Host: orderer.example.com
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer2.example.com
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer3.example.com
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer4.example.com
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer5.example.com
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/tls/server.crt
            Addresses:
                - orderer.example.com:7050
                - orderer2.example.com:7050
                - orderer3.example.com:7050
                - orderer4.example.com:7050
                - orderer5.example.com:7050
```

Docker-compose-etcdraft2.yaml (eg. orderer3 section)

```
  orderer3.example.com:
    extends:
      file: base/peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    container_name: orderer3.example.com
    networks:
    - byfn
    volumes:
        - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
        - orderer3.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
    - 9050:7050
```

Following the same pattern I think that connection.json should be updated including all the orderers with its port, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All orderers are listening on port 7050 of the containers.

The code below maps the port of the host to container, so your host will redirect traffic to container 7050 port when receiving on 9050.

```
ports:
- 9050:7050
```

Its Because the containers inside the same docker compose can reach each other by using the container port.

This 9050, 8050, would only be useful in case you need to reach them from outside docker-compose.

Comment: Thanks that clarifies me a lot!